# Getting OutOfBoundException during a recursion code

Tags: recursion

Getting the below error while executing the code:

> Exception in thread "main" h
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
>       at com.java.program.ReverseString.main(ReverseString.java:17)

```
package com.java.program;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Any String for recurssion");
        String n = s.next();

        System.out.println("The Entered Value is: " + n);
        char str[]= n.toCharArray();
        for (int i= str.length-1;i >= 0; i++) {
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You assign 'i' to the length and instead of decreasing it, you keep increasing it with i++, change it to i--

Comment: Your code is not using recursion. If this is for some kind of homework assignment, make sure you are using recursion to reverse the string.

Comment: Thanks Kacper and Allen. It worked.

Yes it was for self practice